# Questions on how to talk about specifics, how to talk about things in relation to other things

Tags: comparison

Say you're at an event and you want to say, I like **this** specific event.

Let's say basketball, is 我喜欢这篮球比赛 correct?

And in comparison, 这篮球比赛比昨周篮球比赛很好。That doesn't look right, so I'm

curious on how to formulate these types of statements.

Comment: 昨周 sounds a bit Japanese to me. Most people will be able to guess its meaning, but 上个星期 is more common as 'last week'. 这篮球比赛 is missing a classifier (make sure you know what a classifier is). For sport events 场 is the most commonly used one, thus 这场篮球比: this basketball game.

Comment: To compare the quality of two things, 很好 is not correct. You should use X比Y好 (X is better than Y) or X比Y好得多 (X is much better than Y).

Comment: although 这 is a demonstrative pronoun，it is often used w／o CL，also as preceding comment says，there should be no 很 in front of 好，instead could use 还要好，or 更好

Answer (score 1):

You can say 这场篮球赛比上周那场更好。or 这场篮球赛比上周那场好的多。